# C# How to get stream ffmpeg video?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, stream

I'm trying to get ffmpeg stream video from ip camera. My problem is that i know how to get mpeg stream, but the camera type is ffmpeg. Do you know how to get ffmpeg stream? Is there some simple method as this below to do it? I would like to avoid rtsp implementation becouse it's hard to find some good rtsp documentation. Here is the code to get mpeg streams:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
//using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MJPEGStream stream;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stream = new MJPEGStream("stream_url");
        stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
    }

    void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

Comment: I know very little about ffmpeg but, as far as I know, ffmpeg is a component and not a stream type.

Comment: Your stream from IP Camera is whether MP4 or MJPG, but not FFMPEG. FFMPEG is a tools to convert one format to another format.

Comment: But when it uses MPEG it uses also http protocol. FFMPEG uses rtsp protocol and method i wrote above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, only i had to do was adding VLC plugin and now it works and looks like this:

```
 public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://someurl");
             axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
         }
```